# Is it possible to copy files through ftp connection?

Tags: ftp, connection, command

I use the following code to put a file from my local machine to a remote machine:

```
open abc
a
b
lcd C:\Interfaces\KGR-ARV\XML
ascii
prompt
prompt
cd /usr/qkreditnethome/interface/temp
put C:\Interfaces\KGR-ARV\XML\*KGRRequest*QUA.XML
Y
quit
bye
```

Is there a way, using a ftp command, to copy the file from /usr/qkreditnethome/interface/temp to /usr/qkreditnethome/interface/temp2 ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: belongs to http://superuser.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the OS you can take some third-party software which mounts the remote FTP as a part of the local filesystem, and then use regular system copy routines.

Answer (score 1):

There is no copy command in ftp.  You will have to GET the file and PUT it where you want.